# How to ignore @FeignClient apis from being processed by swagger?

Tags: swagger, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger and Feign in one project, and the swagger will take `@RequestMapping` annotated methods and create the documentation. But this is weird to do so for classes and methods annotated by both `@FeightClient` and `@RequestMapping`. So how to ignore these apis in swagger? Which class of swagger
do the scan job so that I could learn and add some other class to ignore these apis annotated by `@FeightClient`?

```
@FeignClient(name = TodoItemRpcRepository.SERVICE_NAME)
@RequestMapping("/api/todos")
public interface TodoItemRpcRepository {

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  TodoItem findById(@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") final String token,  //
      @PathVariable("id") final Long id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `@RequestMapping` over the `@FeignClient` annotated class and add a `path` attribute in the `@FeignClient`. This time, issue was resolved perfectly. I guess `@RequestMapping` is not permitted to `@FeignClient` annotated class.

```
@FeignClient(name = TodoItemRpcRepository.SERVICE_NAME, name="/api/todos")
public interface TodoItemRpcRepository {

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  TodoItem findById(@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") final String token,  //
      @PathVariable("id") final Long id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docket `select` you can specify a predicate. You could use the [withClassAnnotation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.6.0/springfox/documentation/builders/RequestHandlerSelectors.html) method to specify `@FeignClient` as the annotation. You'd need to combine it with  the `Predicates.not` to ignore in your case.

Comment: Yes, I tried this like bellow: `select().apis(not(withClassAnnotation(ApiIgnore.class))).build()`. But the spring still pick up the @RequestMapping class and did the mapping the way to map a controller.